# Reopening an IO Stream vs. just using the new Stream

Tags: ruby, io

In the Ruby-Docs it gives the example of:

```
f1 = File.new("testfile")
f2 = File.new("testfile")
f2.readlines[0]   #=> "This is line one\n"
f2.reopen(f1)     #=> #<File:testfile>
f2.readlines[0]   #=> "This is line one\n"
```

My question is why reopen `f2` when you could just `f2.close` and `f1.readlines[0]`? Are there any advantages to reopening with a new stream vs. just using the new stream?

Answer (score 1):

I talked to some devs on IRB a while back and the response I got was that it was mostly used for changing the `$std` variables to modify where methods such as `puts` and `print` output to...

```
$stdout.reopen(File.open('log'))
puts 'hello world'
```

The reason for using this rather than...

```
$stdout = File.open('log')
```

...was kinda up in the air though. I had one dev that said that direct assignment didn't play well with some of ruby's C functions. I don't know much about C and can't say much about this, but he pointed me to some [minitest source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/minitest/unit.rb#L477-L495) to see an example of it in use. However, apparently even the source has switched over to direct assignment vs. reopening since the dev last looked at it.

In conclusion... from the looks of it `IO#reopen` might be useless, but I would love to hear an argument against this.

**Update**

Ok, so I reread over the documentation and saw that there was a second set of opts for `reopen`:

```
reopen(path, mode_str) → ios
```

This actually seems somewhat useful as opposed to the `reopen(other_IO) → ios` option.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the main difference is that with `reopen`, the new stream would apply not only to subsequent uses of the `$std...` variable, but also to variables that *previously* were assigned the value of the  `$std...` variable. This can be good or bad, depending on your situation.

This irb session shows that with `reopen`, a variable that was assigned previous to the stream change will acquire the newly changed stream. Note that the `fileno` does not change for either variable, and both variables produce no output:

```
> $stderr.fileno
 => 2
> stderr_copy = $stderr
 => #<IO:<STDERR>>
> stderr_copy.fileno
 => 2
> $stderr.reopen(File.open('/dev/null', 'w'))
 => #<File:/dev/null>
> stderr_copy.fileno
 => 2
> $stderr.fileno
 => 2
> $stderr.puts 'foo'
 => nil
> stderr_copy.puts 'foo'
 => nil
```

In contrast, when instead of using `reopen`, the newly opened `/dev/null` File object is *assigned to* `$stderr`, `stderr_copy` will retain its original output stream. Only `$stderr` gets the new `fileno`, and `stderr_copy` still produces output:

```
> $stderr.fileno
 => 2
> stderr_copy = $stderr
 => #<IO:<STDERR>>
> stderr_copy.fileno
 => 2
> $stderr = File.open('/dev/null', 'w')
 => #<File:/dev/null>
> $stderr.fileno
 => 10
> stderr_copy.fileno
 => 2
> $stderr.puts 'foo'
 => nil
> stderr_copy.puts 'foo'
foo
 => nil
```

If you want to use `reopen`, but want to save a copy of the original output stream, you can use `dup`:

```
> stderr_dup = $stderr.dup
 => #<IO:<STDERR>>
> stderr_dup.fileno
 => 10
> $stderr.reopen(File.open('/dev/null', 'w'))
 => #<File:/dev/null>
> $stderr.fileno
 => 2
> stderr_dup.puts 'foo'
foo
 => nil
> $stderr.puts 'foo'
 => nil
```