# Output redirection troubleshooting in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stdout

So I'm trying to redirect output to a file temporarily:

```
  prev_std = STDOUT

  $stdout.reopen(@filename, 'w:UTF-8')

  # stuff happens here with @filename and lots of output

  $stdout = prev_std
```

but when I do this, it seems as though I can't redirect it back afterwards. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `reopen` on `STDOUT` since `$stdout` is just a global  variable that points to the same object. This permanently changes `STDOUT`.

What about this:

```
$stdout = File.open(@filename, 'w:UTF-8')

# ...

$stdout = prev_std
```

Comment: Solved the problem neatly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`STDOUT` is a constant that represents the standard output, which is an `IO` object. And `$stdout` is a global variable whose default values is usually `STDOUT` itself, by default, both point to the same object:

```
$stdout.object_id == STDOUT.object_id => true
```

If you call a method on one of them, the other one will be affected. So if you call a method using `$stdout` it will also take effect on `STDOUT`. Calling `reopen` on `$stdout` will affect `STDOUT` as well (even if it's a constant).

If you want to redirect output to a file temporarily and restore it then to the standard output, you should assign `$stdout` a new `IO` object:

```
$stdout = File.open('/path/to/file', 'w:UTF-8')
puts "this will go to the file"
$stdout = STDOUT
puts "this will go to standard output!"
```

See also the following questions:

- [What is the difference between Ruby's $stdout and STDOUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671716/what-is-the-difference-between-rubys-stdout-and-stdout)
- [What is the difference between STDIN and $stdin in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279604/what-is-the-difference-between-stdin-and-stdin-in-ruby)
- [Reopening an IO Stream vs. just using the new Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616482/reopening-an-io-stream-vs-just-using-the-new-stream)
- And [The IO reopen method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-i-reopen) along with the rest of IO methods.